# How do I pagination using query limit, offset, and jquery datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datatable, pagination

I made a page using the data table. However, as the number of data increases, the speed of data loading slows down, so we try to proceed paging. But I don't know how to modify it in the current code. How should it be modified?

in this my datatable scipt

```
 $(function() {

          $('#datatable1').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            order: [[ 1, "desc" ], [ 2, "desc"]],
            language: {


              searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
              sSearch: '',
              lengthMenu: '_MENU_ items/page',
            },
            dom : 'Bfrtip',

            buttons: [
                'copy', 'excel', 'print'
            ]
          });
        });
```

in this sql query

```
    $sql = "SELECT id,  DATE_FORMAT(tranDate,'%Y-%m-%d') as tranDate, tranTime, date, cmd, paymethod, amount, orgRefNo, orgTranDate FROM noti_card_data  WHERE  mbrNO = '1'";

in this table view code


    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){               

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                echo "<table id='datatable1' class = table style = 'width: 100%; font-size:12.5px; font-family:nanum; background-color:transparent;'>";
                echo "<thead >";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>No</th>";
                echo "<th>amount</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";

                echo "<tbody>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . number_format($row['amount']) . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
                echo "</tbody>";                            
                echo "</table>";
                // Free result set
                mysqli_free_result($result);                                  
            } 

            else{

            }
        }     

    else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    } 

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
```

in this view
[image]

how to using pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the data sets that you need for the current page that your pagination is in instead of getting all the data sets that your query returns.

For ex:

Imagine you are in page 1 in the pagination.And if you need just 100 items per a page then you can limit the items that your query retrieves to 100 and by doing that it will make more faster in retrieving data since instead of  getting every data set from the query  you are just getting 100 to display in the current page.

You have to pass the page number in the url. imagine your url is like something that is mentioned below.

http://localhost/pagination.php?page=2

```
  // getting the current page to set the starting point to get data.
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $curPage = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
      $curPage = 1;
    }

    //number of items you need per a page
     $labels_per_page = 100;

     //setting the starting point according to the page no.                  
 if($curPage>1){
     $start = ($curPage-1)*$labels_per_page;
  }else{
     $start = 0;
  }                     

//limiting the query according to the starting point nd items per page
$sql = "SELECT id,  DATE_FORMAT(tranDate,'%Y-%m-%d') as tranDate, tranTime, date, cmd, paymethod, amount, orgRefNo, orgTranDate FROM noti_card_data  WHERE  mbrNO = '1' LIMIT ".$start .','.$labels_per_page ;
```

result view
[image]

I want view

[image]

Comment: Nothing is printed out.

Comment: that must be because you might not get a value for the `$curPage`.echo it and check if you get a value

Comment: I have edited the answer.You might get an idea now i gues. @전준휘

Comment: Thank you. But it's still slow when you bring in the entire data. I want to bring 10 per page, but it seems to bring the whole page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215275/discussion-between--and-hirumina).

Comment: After url, I change the page number and bring up 10 data each. However, only one page number is displayed. Why is that?

Comment: You have to change the page numbers in the pagination it self.ex: if you click on 3 that url must change to http://localhost/pagination.php?page=3